# SQL Update: Invalid object name 'master.dbo.TsqlSplit'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a really weird error. I am trying to run a stored procedure, that works perfectly on our production environment. Now, on our test server, I get the `Invalid object name 'master.dbo.TsqlSplit'.` error.

I have the code below, and it fails when it executes the scalar (and gives the invalid error).

```
 bool res = false;
            using (
                var conn =
                    new SqlConnection(
                        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VirksomhedsborsRestrictedAccess"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.Saxis_UpdateCreateAdvert";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdvertId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.AdvertID;
                //this.ActivatedDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.Address.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdvertLevel", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.AdvertLevel.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdvertType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.AdvertTypeRaw.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BusinessEntityType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.BusinessEntityType.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CanMove", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = this.CanMove.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.City.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.CompanyName.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Competition", SqlDbType.NText).Value = this.Competition.Value.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.ContactEmail.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.ContactName.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactTelephone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.ContactTelephone.NullToDbNull();
                //this.CreatedDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NText).Value = this.Description.Value.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Employees", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.Employees.HasValue ? (int)this.Employees.Value : (object)DBNull.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpiryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.ExpiryDate.NullToDbNull(); // Expiry date extended package
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FinancingBySeller", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = this.FinancingBySeller.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FinancingInterest", SqlDbType.Float).Value = this.FinancingInterest.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FinancingMonths", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.FinancingMonths.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FinancingPayout", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = this.FinancingPayout.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FoundedYear", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.FoundedYear.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FurnitureIncluded", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = (this.Furniture == null ? DBNull.Value : this.Furniture.IsIncluded.NullToDbNull());
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FurnitureValue", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = (this.Furniture == null ? DBNull.Value : this.Furniture.Value.NullToDbNull());
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdealPartner", SqlDbType.NText).Value = this.IdealPartner.Value.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@OperationType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)this.OperationType;

                // Must have room for 9 images. Filenames are GUID + .ext + separator
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Images", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 400).Value = this.Images != null ? string.Join(",", this.Images.ConvertAll(f => f.Filename).ToArray()) : "";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@OnlyVIPContact", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = this.OnlyVIPContact.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.Price.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrimaryRegion", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.PrimaryRegion.Id.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrimarySector", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.PrimarySector.Id.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProfitBeforeTaxes", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = this.ProfitBeforeTaxes.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RealEstateIncluded", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = this.RealEstate == null ? DBNull.Value : this.RealEstate.IsIncluded.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RealEstateValue", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = this.RealEstate == null ? DBNull.Value : this.RealEstate.Value.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReasonForSale", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.ReasonForSale.NullToDbNull();

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Regions", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 400).Value = this.Regions != null ? string.Join(",", this.Regions.ConvertAll(r => r.Id.ToString()).ToArray()) : "";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RevenuePrediction", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.RevenuePrediction.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RevenueStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.RevenueStatus.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchTerms", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.SearchTerms != null ? string.Join(",", this.SearchTerms.ToArray()) : "";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sectors", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 400).Value = this.Sectors != null ? string.Join(",", this.Sectors.ConvertAll(s => s.Id.ToString()).ToArray()) : "";

                if (this.AdvertLevel == AdvertLevel.Regular
                    && (this.Status == AdvertStatus.Enabled
                     || this.Status == AdvertStatus.ApprovedNotPublished
                     || this.AdvertID == -1)) 
                    this.Status = AdvertStatus.PendingApproval;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.Status.NullToDbNull();

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StockIncluded", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = this.Stock == null ? DBNull.Value : this.Stock.IsIncluded.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StockValue", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = this.Stock == null ? DBNull.Value : this.Stock.Value.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subtitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.Subtitle.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Training", SqlDbType.NText).Value = this.Training.Value.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TransactionType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.TransactionType.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Turnover", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.Turnover.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = this.UserID.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@VATnumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = this.VATNumber.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = this.ZipCode.NullToDbNull();

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyCountry", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = this.CompanyCountry.NullToDbNull();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyZip", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Value = this.CompanyZip.NullToDbNull();

                int id = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (this.AdvertID == -1) this.AdvertID = id;
                res = (this.AdvertID == id);

                conn.Close();
            }
```

My stored procedure is really simple, and looks like this:

```
USE [Virksomhedsbors]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Saxis_UpdateCreateAdvert]    Script Date: 10-09-2014 10:03:23 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Saxis_UpdateCreateAdvert]

@AdvertID INT,
@Address NVARCHAR(200),
@AdvertLevel INT,
@AdvertType NVARCHAR(200),
@BusinessEntityType INT,
@CanMove BIT,
@City NVARCHAR(200),
@CompanyName NVARCHAR(200),
@Competition NTEXT,
@ContactEmail NVARCHAR(200),
@ContactName NVARCHAR(200),
@ContactTelephone NVARCHAR(200),
@Description NTEXT,
@Employees INT,
@ExpiryDate DATETIME,
@FinancingBySeller BIT,
@FinancingInterest FLOAT,
@FinancingMonths INT,
@FinancingPayout BIGINT,
@FoundedYear INT,
@FurnitureIncluded BIT,
@FurnitureValue BIGINT,
@IdealPartner NTEXT,
@Images NVARCHAR(400),
@OnlyVIPContact BIT,
@Price INT,
@PrimaryRegion INT,
@PrimarySector INT,
@ProfitBeforeTaxes BIGINT,
@RealEstateIncluded BIT,
@RealEstateValue BIGINT,
@ReasonForSale INT,
@Regions NVARCHAR(400),
@RevenuePrediction INT,
@RevenueStatus INT,
@SearchTerms NVARCHAR(200),
@Sectors NVARCHAR(400),
@Status INT,
@StockIncluded BIT,
@StockValue BIGINT,
@Subtitle NVARCHAR(200),
@Training NTEXT,
@TransactionType INT,
@Turnover INT,
@UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@VATNumber NVARCHAR(200),
@ZipCode NVARCHAR(50),
@CompanyCountry VARCHAR(3) = NULL,
@CompanyZip NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
@OperationType INT = NULL

AS

IF @AdvertId = -1
BEGIN
    -- CREATE if @AdvertId is -1

    DECLARE @now DATETIME
    SET @now = GETDATE()

    DECLARE @EV BIT
    SET @EV = 0

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SELECT @EV = EmailVerified 
            FROM [User]
            WHERE MembershipId=@UserId

        SET @EV = ISNULL(@EV, 0)

        INSERT INTO Advert (
            CreatedDate,
            ModifiedDate,
            EmailVerified,
            EmailVerificationGuid,
            Address,
            AdvertLevel,
            AdvertType,
            BusinessEntityTypeID,
            CanMove,
            City,
            CompanyName,
            DescCompetition,
            ContactEmail,
            ContactName,
            ContactTelephone,
            Description,
            Employees,
            ExpiryDate,
            FinancingBySeller,
            FinancingInterest,
            FinancingMonths,
            FinancingPayout,
            FoundedYear,
            FurnitureIncluded,
            FurnitureValue,
            DescIdealPartner,
            OnlyVIPContact,
            Price,
            Region,
            Sector,
            ProfitBeforeTaxes,
            RealEstateIncluded,
            RealEstateValue,
            ReasonForSale,
            RevenuePrediction,
            RevenueStatus,
            SearchTerms,
            Status,
            StockIncluded,
            StockValue,
            Subtitle,
            DescTraining,
            TransactionType,
            Turnover,
            UserID,
            CVR,
            ZipCode,
            CompanyCountry,
            CompanyZip,
            OperationType
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            @now,
            @now,
            @EV,
            NEWID(),
            @Address,
            @AdvertLevel,
            @AdvertType,
            @BusinessEntityType,
            @CanMove,
            @City,
            @CompanyName,
            @Competition,
            @ContactEmail,
            @ContactName,
            @ContactTelephone,
            @Description,
            @Employees,
            @ExpiryDate,
            @FinancingBySeller,
            @FinancingInterest,
            @FinancingMonths,
            @FinancingPayout,
            @FoundedYear,
            @FurnitureIncluded,
            @FurnitureValue,
            @IdealPartner,
            @OnlyVIPContact,
            @Price,
            @PrimaryRegion,
            @PrimarySector,
            @ProfitBeforeTaxes,
            @RealEstateIncluded,
            @RealEstateValue,
            @ReasonForSale,
            @RevenuePrediction,
            @RevenueStatus,
            @SearchTerms,
            @Status,
            @StockIncluded,
            @StockValue,
            @Subtitle,
            @Training,
            @TransactionType,
            @Turnover,
            @UserID,
            @VATNumber,
            @ZipCode,
            @CompanyCountry,
            @CompanyZip,
            @OperationType
        )

        IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            --SET @AdvertID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()   -- is scope_identity f*cked?     -- maybe because of the trigger

            SELECT TOP 1 @AdvertID = AdvertID FROM Advert WHERE CreatedDate=@now AND UserID=@UserID AND AdvertLevel = @AdvertLevel
            ORDER BY AdvertID DESC

        END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- UPDATE

    SELECT @EV = EmailVerified 
            FROM [User]
            WHERE MembershipId=@UserId

    SET @EV = ISNULL(@EV, 0)

    UPDATE Advert
    SET
        ModifiedDate=GETDATE(),
        Address=@Address,
        AdvertLevel=@AdvertLevel,
        AdvertType=@AdvertType,
        BusinessEntityTypeID=@BusinessEntityType,
        CanMove=@CanMove,
        City=@City,
        CompanyName=@CompanyName,
        DescCompetition=@Competition,
        ContactEmail=@ContactEmail,
        ContactName=@ContactName,
        ContactTelephone=@ContactTelephone,
        Description=@Description,
        Employees=@Employees,
        ExpiryDate=@ExpiryDate,
        FinancingBySeller=@FinancingBySeller,
        FinancingInterest=@FinancingInterest,
        FinancingMonths=@FinancingMonths,
        FinancingPayout=@FinancingPayout,
        FoundedYear=@FoundedYear,
        FurnitureIncluded=@FurnitureIncluded,
        FurnitureValue=@FurnitureValue,
        DescIdealPartner=@IdealPartner,
        OnlyVIPContact=@OnlyVIPContact,
        Price=@Price,
        Region=@PrimaryRegion,
        Sector=@PrimarySector,
        ProfitBeforeTaxes=@ProfitBeforeTaxes,
        RealEstateIncluded=@RealEstateIncluded,
        RealEstateValue=@RealEstateValue,
        ReasonForSale=@ReasonForSale,
        RevenuePrediction=@RevenuePrediction,
        RevenueStatus=@RevenueStatus,
        SearchTerms=@SearchTerms,
        Status=@Status,
        StockIncluded=@StockIncluded,
        StockValue=@StockValue,
        Subtitle=@Subtitle,
        DescTraining=@Training,
        TransactionType=@TransactionType,
        Turnover=@Turnover,
        CVR=@VATNumber,
        ZipCode=@ZipCode,
        UserID=@UserID, -- Allow the Anonymous User ID to be changed
        CompanyCountry = @CompanyCountry,
        CompanyZip = @CompanyZip,
        EmailVerified = @EV,
        OperationType = @OperationType
    WHERE
        AdvertID = @AdvertID
        --AND UserID=@UserID -- Only accept the change the advert if user id is the same

END

IF (ISNULL(@AdvertID, -1) <> -1)
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE FROM AdvertRegion
        WHERE AdvertID = @AdvertID

        INSERT INTO AdvertRegion (AdvertID, RegionID)
        SELECT @AdvertID, Item
        FROM master.dbo.TsqlSplit(@Regions)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE FROM AdvertSector
        WHERE AdvertID = @AdvertID

        INSERT INTO AdvertSector (AdvertID, SectorID)
        SELECT @AdvertId, Item
        FROM master.dbo.TsqlSplit(@Sectors)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE FROM AdImages
        WHERE AdvertID = @AdvertID

        INSERT INTO AdImages (AdvertID, FileName)
        SELECT @AdvertId, Item
        FROM master.dbo.TsqlSplit(@Images)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END

SELECT @AdvertID
```

Any idea what the `master.dbo.TsqlSplit` error could be?

Comment: Could you check your connection string?

Comment: @Steve connectionstring should work fine. It can open to the database, and I can easily make other reads/inserts from the database

Comment: It seems that your proc uses a table/view in the master database called TsqlSplit an there is not such object in your current working server. Or probably a function that splits the @Images parameter and returns a table.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It was inside master->programmability->functions->table-valued functions ... never heard about that before. Let's keep this question open so any happy Googlers can read this hint. THANKS steve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of the StoredProcedure (and also after that point) you use the TSqlSplit object.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DELETE FROM AdvertRegion
    WHERE AdvertID = @AdvertID

    INSERT INTO AdvertRegion (AdvertID, RegionID)
    SELECT @AdvertID, Item
    FROM master.dbo.TsqlSplit(@Regions)
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I suppose, from its name, that it is a function that splits the parameters @Regions, @Images and @Sectors and returns a table used to insert new records in the AdvertRegion, AdvertSector and AdImages tables. You mentioned also that this code works without problems in your production server but not in your test server. So, the only possible reason of the error is the fact that this function is missing in your test server.